# How to optimize memory usage while using Spark SQL Temporary View and Cassandra Row Cache?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to figure out how to reduce load on memory by avoiding data duplication, while querying cassandra through Spark SQL.

By default, does cassandra store data in memory as per row cache size ? 
If yes, then will same data be duplicated if I create following temporary view using SQL or create a Dataset ? or Spark will smartly leverage data cached by cassandra ?

```
val createDDL = """CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW words
     USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
     OPTIONS (
     table "words",
     keyspace "test",
     cluster "Test Cluster",
     pushdown "true")"""
spark.sql(createDDL)
```

Any insights into optimizing memory usage will be highly appreciated.

Thanks